# Is it possible to distribute an unfinished iOS app for closed-beta tests using Apple Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, beta

We'd like to do some closed-beta tests of our app using App Store.

We know about the ad-hoc way, but it needs testers' UDIDs to be gathered upfront and embedded in the provisioning profile, which isn't ideal, because we'd like to avoid asking 100 testers for their UDIDs.

Another way is to use the Enterprise Distribution which doesn't need gathering and storing UDIDs, but let's talk about another possibility...

The user needs to login when the app starts. User accounts can't be created from the app, so we're thinking about creating some beta-tester accounts on the server, submitting the beta-version of the app to Apple Store and sending the credentials to the beta-testers via email.

The only question is whether it's a recommended practice to submit an unfinished app to Apple Store. After submission all iOS users will be able to download the app, but only the beta-testers will be able to login. It has also an additional advantage, which is knowing Apple's feedback earlier, so any issues can be addressed earlier too. Do you think Apple will approve an unfinished app?

Also, is it possible to disable application reviews for an application submitted to Apple Store? We don't want to get bad reviews from users during beta-tests...

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: The Appstore is not the place to beta test an app, it states this clearly in the guidelines. https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html (see 2.9)

Comment: @Luke : Lots of beta testing goes on in App store apps (using analytics).  It's just not obviously apparent that these are not fully functional apps.  And all customers become beta testers.

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: We did it using Testflight App.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple answer. No.

Detailed answer. No, Apple requires that applications in the app store be final products. You can attempt to slip it through so long as you don't call it a beta or make any reference to it not being completed. In doing this method you are skirting Apple's rules which could result in having your developer license revoked.

More information can be found HERE--> https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ <--HERE

Edit to add: No you can't disable reviews in tha app store.

Comment: Formal is your answer correct, but informal it is sometimes used the way the M.F. describe it. Best example for me was the app "Mailbox", when you downloaded it, it was not functional. You had to register and by the time you got approved and could use the app.

Comment: this answer is no longer correct due to TestFlight

Comment: @Fluidity TestFlight is not the Apple Store. It is an Apple Beta Service, but still not the App Store.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 testflight is in the appstore and is the exact answer to the question.

Comment: @Fluidity TestFlight is an app in the app store, yes. But it is not distributing via the App Store.

Answer (score 16):

It is possible now to use [TestFlight Beta Testing](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/), with a current limit of 1,000 invites and without the need of asking and registering UDIDs.

Comment: This is the new best answer

Answer (score 5):

Beta test apps are explicitly prohibited by Apple's App store guidelines.

However if you don't explicitly label or advertise an app as Beta test, and the app appears fully functional and otherwise acceptable, then Apple might approve the submission.

It is actually quite common for developers to submit unfinished apps and put them in the App store (see the "minimum viable product" style of development).  However the unfinished features have to not be apparent and not mentioned anywhere in the apps description or documentation, so that the app appears to be fully functional to the reviewers (e.g. if some feature is missing, then hide the button and documentation for it so that no one knows that something is missing).  I've got an app in the App store that only has 5 or so of the many dozens of features on my original design spec.  No one knows (until now :)

There is no way to limit app downloads to only specific testers (other than using Ad Hoc, Enterprise or B2B accounts) for closed testing, and there is no way to prevent bad reviews and ratings.  You can limit app availability by country and by day, and submit no search keywords to limit exposure.  You could try pricing your app too high and gifting the app to your testers if you are willing to give Apple 30% of the high price per copy.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% certain that Apple wouldn't allow that, mainly because you are stopping the majority of people from using the app. Also because you're submitting an unfinished app.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the Apple Developer guidelines correctly, you cannot distribute your beta app to **any** external entities (public customers, friends etc) *other* than using TestFlight's external testing suite. A lot of folks (and your question mentioned it) talk about AdHoc as a way around this. If you look at the Apple Developer website and try to add a device to your dev account, they pretty clearly give a warning ([see image from SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125241/ios-apps-external-beta-testing-apple-restrictions)) that states that Ad Hoc devices are only to be used for **internal** organizational use, or if you are a legal agent (i.e. consulting firm hired to create an app for a company) of that organization. Based on this I don't think AdHoc gets you off the hook from using TestFlight for external beta testing.