# iOS apps external beta testing Apple restrictions

Tags: ios, testflight, crashlytics, hockeyapp, app-distribution

After reading numerous beta testing strategy guides for iOS I'm still confused about if it's permitted by Apple's Developer Program to distribute an app for **external** beta testing without getting it approved by them and using TestFlight. For example, is it allowed to create an AdHoc signed app and use a 3rd party tool (Crashlytics, HockeyApp, others) to beta distribute to external entities. External in this case meaning **not** within your organization. Within an organization, there are other means that can be used like Enterprise Distribution, which have no restrictions but are not allowed to be used externally. The question is: does Apple allow external beta testing for a non-Apple signed app? (non-Apple as opposed to TestFlight which would indeed sign it for external testing via iTunesConnect submission).

UPDATE: after looking into AdHoc and going to the Apple Developer page, it shows this (note the Pre-Release warning in that image) which seems to point to what I suspected - per Apple's rules, you cannot let **external** folks test your ad hoc app:
[image]

So if this is true, I don't see how there's any way around TestFlight for public external betas.

Comment: Before Apple bought testflight, we used to do it all the time.  You'd have to create a provisioning file that had the device id.    However, it's a lot easier just to do it via Apple TestFlight.  Approval for beta usually only takes a day or less.

Comment: Completely agree with you abt Testflight and yes you CAN do Ad Hoc with device UUIDs. My question is using an AdHoc profile app ok with Apple for external use (public beta testing)?

Comment: @stonedauwg Yes it is possible to distribute a Testflight build with adhoc profile and it will work for external users as well. But Apple recommends to use Appstore profile in Testflight build.

Comment: @Unni what I meant was is it ok to use AdHoc dev-signed apps for external clients to test via HockeyApp or other means? Or do they only allow TestFlight for external customers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Ad-Hoc distribution with external testers is perfectly fine and has been used like that by thousands of developers world wide for years.
Quoting Apple's [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1):

> Testers don’t need to be team members or iTunes Connect users to run the app, but their devices need to be registered in your developer account.

Comment: In Apple documentation parlance, "team member" refers to Developer Account team member. So yes, you don't need to be a member of the dev team to test using ad hoc or testflight. However, other signs point to Apple not allowing "pre release" software to be distro'ed outside of your company. Thats what I'm trying to clear up.

Comment: This is referring to _Apple's_ prerelease software, i.e. iOS 10 beta or whatever, not _your_ prerelease software.
Additionally, Apple has been loosening their NDAs and restrictions regarding iOS prerelease versions over the last years too, so it might even be that this page is partly out of date.

Answer (score 1):

According to the current [Apple Developer Program](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Documentation/License_Agreements__Apple_Developer_Program/Apple_Developer_Program_Agreement_20150909.pdf) agreement (bolding of text is mine):

> 7.3 Distribution on Registered Devices (Ad Hoc Distribution)
>   Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement, You may also distribute Your Applications
>   for iOS, watchOS and tvOS **to individuals within Your company, organization, educational
>   institution, group, or who are otherwise affiliated with You** for use on a limited number of
>   Registered Devices (as specified on the Program web portal)

See also section 7.3 parts A and B where they clearly allow external testing via TestFlight. Based on that it seems to comfirm that external testing is only allowed via TestFlight. Internal testing can use TestFlight, Enterprise Program-signed apps or Ad Hoc.

Comment: What leads you to believe that "individuals […] who are otherwise affiliated with You" does not include external beta testers? Although IANAL, I'd argue that "being your beta tester" automatically constitutes a form of affiliation.

Comment: You make a valid point and our company has researched that very phrase before but came to the conclusion that it meant a business relationship, not general Joe Public. Why? Because Apple's use of that term ('affiliate') elsewhere in the document suggests that means a business relationship, like a sub-contractor, consultant etc. Obviously without being a lawyer I can't interpret that for sure. If Apple just meant "anyone you feel like", I don't think the above language would need to be as wordy - could just say "anyone" and be done with it

Answer (score 0):

HockeyApp do support app distribution by using an Ad Hoc profile.

You need to buy an apple dev program, then you need to create the profiles and use the profile in your projects, then you need to create a new app in your dashboard on HockeyApp(https://rink.hockeyapp.net/manage/dashboard) and integrate our SDK in your build, you could integrate the SDK by following steps in this KB:
https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/hockeyapp-for-ios

After these you need to upload the build, profile, symbols to HockeyApp.
We recommend use our interactive SDK integration wizard in HockeyApp for Mac(https://www.hockeyapp.net/releases/mac) which covers the steps of integration SDK and upload files to HockeyApp.

For more information about distribution please see here:
https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/app-management-2/how-to-organize-development-and-production-apps-for-distribution#hockeyapp-offers-four-pre-defined-release-types

Comment: Understood, but the question isn't does HockeyApp support it - does Apple ALLOW it - meaning Ad Hoc and external customers?

Comment: @stonedauwg Ad-Hoc builds are perfectly fine to be distributed to external testers. They have been used for years like this without any problems.

Comment: @Lukas-Spieß I hear that statement a lot, which is what prompted my question. But does that warning Apple shows in the above photo mean anything? Is that not what they really mean?